# React.js cycle of life when updating data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**What I want :**

I have a node.js server, a captor and a react.js client. Each time the captor detect something it sends a message by socket.io to my node server which return data to my React website (in JSON).

I want that each time my client React.js received new data from my server, it automatically refresh the specified component (generally charts).

**My Code :**

Index.jsx

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: []};
    socket.on('dataCards', function (cards) {
      this.state = {data: cards};
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <NavBarTop />
        <div className="row">
          <NavFilter />
          <div className="col-sm-7-5 col-md-7-5" id="mainPage">
            <DataAnalytics />
            <CardsList data={this.state.data} />
          </div>
          <Interventions />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

cardlist.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  rawMarkup() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ticket">
        <h2 className="cardUID">
          {this.props.uid}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

I'm not very familiar with React.js cycle of life. Unfortunately render is called before that data arrived to my client. So when cardlist.jsx is called props.data is null.

I don't know how to structure my code to do what I want...

Anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have data in render the first time through. Just throw up a loading indicator or something in the meantime. You should do your data loading in either componentDidMount or componentWillMount.

Comment: Even In componentWillMount a console.log in the constructor of cardlist is called before the WillMount. It's this that I don't understand... So when cardlist is called this.state is empty

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setState function in order to update your state. It would trigger rerender of your component. Use "this.state = something" only to set initial state of your component.

```
socket.on('dataCards', (cards) => {
    this.setState({data: cards});
});
```

And you probably would like to use componentWillMount or componentDidMount lifecycle hooks to listen to socket.io and stop listening upon componentWillUnmount hook.

```
componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('dataCards', (cards) => {
        this.setState({data: cards});
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    socket.off('dataCards');
}
```

Also your Card component looks weird to me. But I have no detailed information about your code to give some advice.

Comment: Yes you're right I forgot this.setState, unfortunately i have this error : this.setState is not a function :/ Yes my component is maybe weird I expiriment react.js

Comment: I assume you are using ES6, then just use arrow function for callback to get context automaticcaly bind for you

Comment: Yes thank you, it delete the error, but I have this error now : Cannot read property 'map' of null. In my component Cardlist This.state.data is null. The render of cardlist is still called before that my data arrived from my server.

Comment: I suppose you removed this.state = {data: []}; from constructor. Don't do this. You need to provide initial state.

Comment: If I instance a getInitialState with this.state = {data : []} I have this eror : getInitialState was defined on App, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead? I have to put a constructor. How can call the render when my data arrived by socket.io

Comment: Look, I'm not your debugging tool and not your documentation to React.